# tooltip issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip

I want to display html table as tooltip in jquery.I have my own css and I want to use

```
.tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
```

Here is my jquery

```
$("#currency1").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});
```

Here is my html

```
<a id="currency1"><div id="currencyresult1">AED 22222</div></a>
```

Complete detail is in this jsfiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/4YDGp/2/

(I know some images are missing in the fiddle but it doesn't work with images either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4YDGp/7/

for the tooltip to disappear when its source/itself(tooltip) is not being 
hovered over there is a `delay`. this `delay` is set on the top, this is something which you can adjust as you please.

```
var delay = 800;

$("#currency1").mouseover(function(){
    //tooltip();
    $('.tooltip').show({ effect: 'slide'});
});

$('.tooltip').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hovering');
});

$('.tooltip').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hovering');
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!$('.tooltip').hasClass('hovering')){
            $('.tooltip').hide();
        }
    }, delay)
});

$("#currency1").mouseleave(function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!$('.tooltip').hasClass('hovering')){
            $('.tooltip').hide();
        }
    }, delay)
});
```

Comment: did you hover over the AED 22222? Since there is an effect applied there would be a delay.

Comment: yes i checked it..still not working..please check your fiddle first

Comment: did that, on hovering over the text the tooltip appears; does nothing appear for you? the img links are broken as you pointed out, which browser are you using?

Comment: its working, however when i checked it on firefox right now nothing appeared because the css was set that way (no borders/text color is white/img links are broken) I added a border to the table to show the tooltip here: http://jsfiddle.net/4YDGp/4/

Comment: @Relfor:i found an issue,when i have more <a> for mouse move,all of them shows tooltip at once..please check this http://jsfiddle.net/mF6qV/

Comment: see Methew, each tooltip needs to be uniquely identified. we didn't look at this part originally as it didn't come up then. here is a solution to the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mF6qV/2/ note that the selection is now done on the basis of classes, this option scales up very well. the identification of tooltips is based on ids which are unique. just a small note, next time you can always post a separate question, this was the answer which is visible clearly can benefit other people who have to deal with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

With [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) this method also works (here the selector relates to `div#currency1`):

```js
$("#currency1").tooltip({
    effect: 'slide',
    content: function() {
        return $('div.tooltip').html();
    },
    open: function(event, ui){
        $(ui.tooltip).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

You only need [to fix that invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2F4YDGp%2F2%2Fshow&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) (move the anchor into the div)

```html
<div id="currency1" title="aaaaa"><a id="currencyresult1">AED 22222</a></div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YDGp/9/)